# Uniform convergence of sequence to the exponent function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_n(z) = (1-z^2/n)^n$, and let $f(z)=\operatorname{exp}(-z^2)$. I need to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in any closed disc.

I saw this: [Uniform Convergence of an Exponential Sequence of Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119872/19341), but I'm not sure the methods used there are applicable here because we're talking about the complex plane, and the logarithm function doesn't behave nicely there.

Comment: Why can't you use [Peter's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119898/19341)? (no $\log$ involved)

Comment: Thanks. Must've missed that. I'm trying to expand e^z to degree n such as the remainder is epsilon/2, and this is what I get:
$\left|e^w-(1+w/n)^n\right| = \left|\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{w^k}{k!} + w^{n+1}g_{n+1}(w) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{w^k}{n^k}\right| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{|w|^k}{k!}\left|\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}-1\right|$
I can't really continue from here because $|w|^k$ can be quite large as $k \approx n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to use the logarithm in the complex plane. Given a closed disk $\{z:|z|\le R\}$, consider only  $n>R^2$: this guarantees $|z^2/n|<1$, and therefore places $1-z^2/n$ in the open right halfplane, where we have the principal branch of $\log$. By the definition of derivative,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty } n\log(1-z^2/n)= -z^2 \lim_{n\to\infty }  \frac{\log(1-z^2/n)-\log 1}{-z^2/n} = -z^2$$
(using $(\log \zeta)'=1$ at $\zeta=1$). This is a lot easier than messing with binomial coefficients.